# SQL Server Union Selections with Different 'Where' clauses to a single Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Currently I am listing out a group of data with separate "UNION"ed select statements which creates a new row entry for each piece of information:

Example:

```
  (No column name)
1  40
2  11
3  13
4  29
5  64
6  34
```

What I want is to change that into a row with labeled columns.

Example:

```
  Column 1   Column 2   Column 3   Column 4   Column 5   Column 6
1   40          11         13         29         64         34
```

How would i go about doing that?

Comment: Pivot table https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample/

Comment: I have no doubt that reference is correct, but I'm having a hard time following the example listed at that link and applying it to my situation.

Comment: Take a look at the answer and just modify the aggregate and column names to what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Val INT, SortOrder VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @T
SELECT 40,'Column 1'
UNION
SELECT 11,'Column 2'
UNION
SELECT 13,'Column 3'
UNION
SELECT 29,'Column 4'
UNION
SELECT 64,'Column 5'
UNION
SELECT 34,'Column 6'

SELECT * FROM @T
pivot (avg (Val) for SortOrder in (
 [Column 1],[Column 2],[Column 3],[Column 4],[Column 5],[Column 6])
) as Whatever
```

rextester: http://rextester.com/LWZH64528

results:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|       40 |       11 |       13 |       29 |       64 |       34 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Date as first column value

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Val VARCHAR(20), SortOrder VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @T
SELECT '2016-10-12','Column 1'
UNION
SELECT '11','Column 2'
UNION
SELECT '13','Column 3'
UNION
SELECT '29','Column 4'
UNION
SELECT '64','Column 5'
UNION
SELECT '34','Column 6'

SELECT * FROM @T
pivot (MAX(Val) for SortOrder in ([Column 1],[Column 2],[Column 3],[Column 4],[Column 5],[Column 6])) as Whatever
```

Result:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|2016-10-12|       11 |       13 |       29 |       64 |       34 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much this works wonderfully.

The next thing I need is one of those values to be a date, and when I pivot for the Date to be what is listed in the first column.

Any input on how to do that?

Comment: @obizues Do you want the value of Column 1 to be a date or the column name to be the date?. Check if my edit is what you want.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, I was having a brainfart.  Essentially each select I just needed to add a  "getDate" method and declare that in the initial table.  Then I just left that out of the pivot statement since it isn't part of what is being pivoted from or on.  Thanks again!